# Finding the PMF of an ordered statistic

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, independence

**Question**

Let $X_0, X_1, X_2, \dots$ be independent and identically distributed continuous random variables with density $f(x)$. Let $N$ be the first index $k$ such that $X_k > X_0$. For example, $N = 1$ if $X_1 > X_0$, $N = 2$ if $X_2 > X_0$ and $X_1 \leq X_0$ and so on. Determine the probability mass function of $N$.

**My thoughts**

I am thinking that $N$ should follow a geometric distribution, since we are somewhat modelling the probability of the first success (i.e. the first $X_k$ exceeding $X_0$) but if so, then what should the parameter for my geometric distribution be? Any intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated :)

**Edit**

Following some help from an answer below and hints from my professor, I now know that my original thought process was not entirely correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> N should follow a geometric distribution... what should the parameter for my geometric distribution be?

That's correct.

To get the parameter observe that

$$P(Y>X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\left[ \int_{x}^{\infty}f(y)dy\right]dx=$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\left[F_Y(y) \right]_{x}^{\infty}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)F(x)dx=1-I$$

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\times F dx=\left[F\times F \right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\times F dx$$

That is

$$2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\times F dx=1$$

and thus

$$I=\frac{1}{2}$$

Conclunding: your geometric parameter is 0.5

---

EDIT: reasoning using the hint of your professor I realized that my answer is not correct. The idea I had now is the following.

The support of N is $n=1,2,3,\dots$

N=1

...easy: $P(N=1)=P(X_1>X_0)=\frac{1}{2}$

N=2

$X_2>X_0>X_1$

This probability is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{6}$

N=3

We must have

$X_0=\max(X_0,X_1,X_2)\rightarrow p=\frac{1}{3}$

AND

$X_3=\max(X_0,X_1,X_2,X_3)\rightarrow p=\frac{1}{4}$

Thus $P(N=3)=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{4}$

by induction...

$$P(N=n)=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$

where $n=1,2,3,\dots$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand the rough idea of it, but I am having some issues understand how you derive $I$. Firstly, is $f \times F$ simply shorthand for $f(x)F(x)$? Secondly, how do you obtain the second equality for $I$?

Comment: @EthanMark: First: yes. Secondly: integrating by parts.

Comment: Hello again! I was pondering a little more on this and had a discussion with my professor. He said that we need to be careful here, since $N$ is conditionally geometric, but not unconditionally geometric. In particular, he hinted that we should be conditioning on $X_0$. With this information, I was wondering if would your answer be calculating the pmf of $N \mid X_0$ instead of $N$?

Comment: @Ethan Mark: your professor is right. An idea that I have is the following:

$n=1,2,3,\dots$

$P(N=n)=P[X_0=\max(X_0,\dots,X_{n-1});X_n=\max(X_0,\dots,X_n)]=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$

I do not know if this argument can be correct, otherwise let me know and I will cancel my answer

Comment: Hmm... I am not sure if it is entirely correct, but it seems like your original one is not really the right way to go about it. Could you perhaps change your answer to what you mentioned above and expound on it a little more? This seems like the right way to go, but I am unclear how you got the two equations for $P(N = n)$...

Comment: @EthanMark: added my latest brainstorming...I checked them with some known distributions (uniform and exponential and it works...)

Answer (score 2):

When the $X_i$'s are i.i.d continuous, the events $A_j=\{X_j=\max\{X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_k\}\}$ are equally likely for every $j=0,1,\ldots,k$ by symmetry.

Further note that $P(A_i\cap A_j)=0$ for every $i\ne j$, so that $$1=P\left(\bigcup_{j=0}^k A_j\right)=\sum_{j=0}^k P(A_j)\implies P(A_j)=\frac1{k+1}\,\,\forall \,j.$$

That is really the main idea needed here.

Your $N$ is defined as $$N=\min\{k\ge 1: X_k>X_0\}$$

So for every $k\in \mathbb N$,

\begin{align}
P(N>k)&=P(X_1\le X_0,X_2\le X_0,\ldots,X_k\le X_0)
\\&=P(X_0=\max\{X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_k\})
\\&=\frac1{k+1}
\end{align}

Hence, $$P(N=k)=P(N>k-1)-P(N>k)=\frac1{k(k+1)}\,,$$ which is certainly not geometric.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I see that $\mathbb{P}(A_i \cap A_j) = 0\ \forall\ i \neq j$, but why this is necessary to show that $\mathbb{P}(A_j) = \frac 1 {k + 1}\ \forall\ j$? I mean, can we not just say that, because all of the $X$'s have equal probability of being the maximum, so we must have $\mathbb{P}(A_j) = \frac 1 {k + 1}\ \forall\ j$?

Comment: Rather, this is a justification for why 'we must have...'.

Comment: Right! And would this be another way of saying that the $A_j$'s form a partition for the $X_i$'s? Not sure if I am saying it correctly...

Comment: Don't think so. That would have been the case if the $A_j$'s were disjoint. Here $P(A_i \cap A_j)=0$ for $i\ne j$ because $X_i$'s are continuous, not because of $A_i \cap A_j=\emptyset$.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for bringing up an old answer, but I am also interested in this question and was wondering why is it that $\mathbb{P}(A_i \cap A_j) = 0\ \forall \ i \neq j$ is a consequence of the $X_i$'s being continuous? Or rather, what would be different if the $X_i$'s were discrete?